# NHibernate / Npgsql throws exception during CreateSchema while debugging UnitTest

Tags: unit-testing, nhibernate, debugging, npgsql

I have two C# projects, Model and ModelTest. Model consists of ActiveRecord objects (wrapper around Hibernate). In ModelTest I created a simple unit test:

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestInitialize]
    public void Init()
    {
        Model.Init();
        Model.CreateSchema();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
    }
}
```

Model.Init() registers all types of assembly Model with ActiveRecord.
Model.CreateSchema() wraps ActiveRecordStarter.CreateSchema(), which calls CreateSchema() of NHibernate.

This code works fine, if I run the unit test, but it fails if I "debug" the unit test. In debug mode, an exception occurs in CreateSchema():

```
NpgsqlException: 'ERROR: 42P01: table "user" does not exist'
```

The exception seems to be raised during the SQL call "drop table user cascade", which obviously fails if the database is empty before running the test. I assume the drop is sent always before creating a new table.

Does Npgsql behave differently in debug mode, regarding the outcome of a drop query?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this?  I'm having the same problem...

Comment: Unfortunately no, I sticked with running unit tests without debug mode..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exact same problem as Tarnschaf -- `SchemaUpdate.Create(...)` would fail and the offending sql was `drop table "tablename" cascade` which resulted in the same "table does not exist" error mentioned above.

It turns out that one of the projects had an reference to a Nhibernate-related assembly that was no longer in the same location.  I'm not sure why this didn't show up when the solution was cleaned & rebuilt.  Removing all references from the project and re-adding them solved the problem (for me).

Just posting this in case it helps someone else down the road.  The Nhibernate exception was less than helpful.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error any more, so I will accept this answer as it is at least a possible reason for my former problem. Thanks.